# import/commit linux file system and unversioned files into svn

Tags: svn, command-line-interface

I am new for SVN. Shall i able to import/commit linux filesystem into SVN? Can u tell me which command is used for it? and how can i import/commit unversioned file into svn repository? and when i use import command ,its says error unknown or unversioned file. if i am using --ignore or add, it wont commit this unversioned file into SVN repository. can u tell me how to import/commit unknown or unversioned file into SVN repository?. unversioned files are char/block device, pipe, FIFO files, etc..

I am using Collabnet subversion edge in suse linux & rapid svn client in fedora linux.

Answer (score 1):

You want the command `svn import`, something like this:

```
svn import <path to directory to be imported> <path to repository>
```

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.tour.importing.html#svn.tour.importing.import

You could also read http://lmgtfy.com/?q=svn+import

Comment: yes, but its says error unknown or unversioned file. if i am using --ignore or add, it wont commit this unversioned file into SVN repository. can u tell me how to import/commit unknown or unversioned file into SVN repository?. unversioned files are char/block device, etc..

Comment: are you now saying you want to add an entire filesystem/char/block device to version control? This sounds like a bad idea to me. This is not how one goes about created a versioning filesystem. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: yes, i need to add an entire filesystem into version control. This will help us to download into anyother machine to compile. is it possible? while import lib.a file is ignored.